# capybara visit doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara

```
describe Inventory::Export do
  describe "export page" do
    it "check to show export page" do
      user = FactoryGirl.build(:admin) 
      activity_type = FactoryGirl.create(:activity_type) 
      visit "/users/sign_in"
      fill_in "user_Login", :with => user.Login
      fill_in "user_password", :with => user.password
      click_button "user_submit"
      visit "/admin/inventory/exports"
      save_and_open_page
    end
  end
end
```

The code at

```
visit "/admin/inventory/exports"
```

doesn't affect to result of

```
save_and_open_page
```

And I get the page which redirected after authorization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
visit admin_inventory_exports_path
```

check your routes for actual path with `rake routes`.